# How can I keep columns in common between two SAS tables to insert data?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I've made a code that allows you to insert data from the SI.SIA table, but sometimes if there's a new column added to the SI.SIA table my program stalls. Isn't there a solution to keep only the columns in common between the two tables (between the LOT.SIN and SI.SIA tables)?

```
proc sql noprint;
select nliteral(name) into :varlist separated by ','
   from dictionary.columns
   where libname="SI" and memname="SIA"
;
insert into LOT.SIN (&varlist. , DateImport) select &varlist. , 
Date() as DateImport
from SI.SIA
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perform an inner join on `dictionary.columns`: one selecting columns from `SI.SIA` and another selecting the columns from `LOT.SIN`.

```
proc sql noprint;
    select nliteral(t1.name)
    into :varlist separated by ','
    from dictionary.columns as t1
    INNER JOIN
         dictionary.columns as t2
    ON upcase(t1.name) = upcase(t2.name)
    where     t1.libname = 'SI'  AND t1.memname = 'SIA'
          AND t2.libname = 'LOT' AND t2.memname = 'SIN'
    ;
quit;
```